# Uppercase word in Java

Tags: java

I'm having some issues with my code.
I was uppercasing a word as usual until I realised for the German users they are getting `SS` instead of `ß`    .
From what I read, it's normal behaviour. But I still want to display `ß` to keep the data consistent.

Any help to check if this letter exists in the sentence and ignore it in the toUpperCase?

```
System.out.println("ßoo".toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Did you try with something like this: `"ßoo".replace("ß", "#").toUpperCase().replace("#", "ß")` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can check every `char` in the `String` and decide if it should be converted to upper case or not, but that leads to some more lines of code than just the method `toUpperCase()`.

I just realized, the method `Character.toUpperCase()` doesn't do the same conversion as `String.toUpperCase()` does, so you can just use a loop and put every `char` to upper case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Bloß keine Großbuchstaben";
    System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());

    // check every single character for 'ß'
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

This outputs

```
BLOSS KEINE GROSSBUCHSTABEN
BLOß KEINE GROßBUCHSTABEN
```